# Quadrature to approximate a transformed beta distribution in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I am using R to run a simulation in which I use a likelihood ratio test to compare two nested item response models. One version of the LRT uses the joint likelihood function L(θ,ρ) and the other uses the marginal likelihood function L(ρ). I want to integrate L(θ,ρ) over f(θ) to obtain the marginal likelihood L(ρ). I have two conditions: in one, f(θ) is standard normal (μ=0,σ=1), and my understanding is that I can just pick a number of abscissa points, say 20 or 30, and use Gauss-Hermite quadrature to approximate this density. But in the other condition, f(θ) is a linearly transformed beta distribution (a=1.25,b=10), where the linear transformation B'=11.14*(B-0.11) is such that B' also has (approximately) μ=0,σ=1.

I am confused enough about how to implement quadrature for a beta distribution but then the linear transformation confuses me even more. My question is threefold: (1) can I use some variation of quadrature to approximate f(θ) when θ is distributed as this linearly transformed beta distribution, (2) how would I implement this in R, and (3) is this a ridiculous waste of time such that there is an obviously much faster and better method to accomplish this task? (I tried writing my own numerical approximation function but found that my implementation of it, being limited to the R language, was just too slow to suffice.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume you can express your L(θ,ρ) and f(θ) in terms of actual code; otherwise you're kinda screwed. Given that assumption, you can use `integrate` to perform the necessary computations. Something like this should get you started; just plug in your expressions for L and f.

```
marglik <- function(rho) {
    integrand <- function(theta, rho) L(theta, rho) * f(theta)
    # set your lower/upper integration limits as appropriate
    integrate(integrand, lower=-5, upper=5, rho=rho)
}
```

For this to work, your integrand has to be *vectorized*; ie, given a vector input for `theta`, it must return a vector of outputs. If your code doesn't fit the bill, you can use `Vectorize` on the integrand function before passing it to `integrate`:

```
integrand <- Vectorize(integrand, "theta")
```

---

Edit: not sure if you're also asking how to define f(θ) for the transformed beta distribution; that seems rather elementary for someone working with joint and marginal likelihoods. But if you are, then the density of B' = a*B + b, given f(B), is

f'(B') = f(B)/a = f((B' - b)/a) / a

So in your case, `f(theta)` is `dbeta(theta/11.14 + 0.11, 1.25, 10) / 11.14`

Comment: Thank you, this is very informative! I do indeed have L(θ,ρ) and f(θ) expressed in terms of actual code. I got all the results I need based on L(θ,ρ), and I was just having a hard time figuring out how to go from L(θ,ρ) to L(ρ). So I don't even need to go the route of quadrature; that is good to know! I will wait to see if anyone feels differently and if not I will mark this as the accepted answer.