# Computing the marginal likelihood of a Gaussian model in R with integrate()

Tags: r, bayesian, numerical-integration, integrate, log-likelihood

I am trying to compute the marginal likelihood of a Gaussian model in R. More precisely, I am trying to integrate the likelihood over both a Gaussian prior on mu and a Gaussian prior on sigma, with some observations yi.

In other words, I am trying to compute:

[image]

I tried to write this in R using the following function (following a similar SA question here: [Quadrature to approximate a transformed beta distribution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918019/quadrature-to-approximate-a-transformed-beta-distribution-in-r)):

```
marglik <- function(data) {

    integrand <-
        Vectorize(function(data, mu, sigma) {
            prod(dnorm(data, mu, sigma) ) * dnorm(mu, 110, 1) * dnorm(sigma, 10, 1)
            } )

    integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf, mu = 100, sigma = 10)$value

}
```

Using this function, I can compute the marginal likelihood of the above model for a set of observations:

```
set.seed(666)

d <- rnorm(100, mean = 107.5, sd = 2.5)
marglik(data = d)

[1] 9.704133e-24
```

However, the results I obtain with this procedure are quite different from results I obtain with grid approximation, or using other packages/softwares.

My question is then: is it possible to do this double integration with integrate ? If it is, how would you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

`integrate()` only takes in univariate functions. That is, the function you put in must be one-dimensional.

In general, such a problem is better tackled using specialised tools, either using something bridgesampling, ie. through the [bridgesampling package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bridgesampling/index.html) if you have MCMC output or the [cubature package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cubature/) if you have more general multivariate integration problems.

However, if we absolutely must do this using `integrate()` twice, we can make this work, but some errors need to be taken out of the code, and . Something like the following would work, although numerically the result seems to be zero most of the time, which is why you would generally try to obtain the log-marginal likelihood.

```
marglik <- function(data) {

  # Function that integrates over mu for given sigma.
  mu_integrand <- Vectorize(function(sigma) {
    mu_given_sigma_fun <- Vectorize(function(mu) {
      prod(dnorm(data, mu, sigma) ) * dnorm(mu, 110, 1) * dnorm(sigma, 10, 1)
      })
    integrate(mu_given_sigma_fun, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)$value
  })

  integrate(mu_integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value

}

set.seed(666)

d <- rnorm(100, mean = 110, sd = 10)
marglik(data = d)
```